# UILabel in detail view is not being populated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITableView populated with an array of data gathered from an SQLite database.  When a cell is selected a detail view is loaded relevant to that cell.  The title on the navigation controller changes ok but a UILabel on the detail view does not get populated.

Relevant tableViewController code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    ExhibitorDetailViewController *exhibitorDetailViewControllerInstance = [[ExhibitorDetailViewController alloc] init];

    exhibitorDetailViewControllerInstance.theTitle = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    exhibitorDetailViewControllerInstance.exhibitorDetailModal = [arrayOfExhibitors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Have tried setting the text before the detail view is loaded wiht the line below
    exhibitorDetailViewControllerInstance.LabelExhibitorDescription.text = arrayOfExhibitors.description;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:exhibitorDetailViewControllerInstance animated:YES];

}
```

The viewDidLoad event of the detail view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = _theTitle; //This sets the title ok

    NSLog(@"0 - %@", _exhibitorDetailModal.description); //This property is what I want to fill the UILabel with

    self.LabelExhibitorDescription.text = _exhibitorDetailModal.description; // This does nothing
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:2.0f];  // If I don't set the background colour here it loads up black (despite being set in the storyboard)


    NSLog(@"label text = %@", self.LabelExhibitorDescription.text); // This shows the text box being null despite having its text property set above

}
```

Detail view header file:

```
@interface ExhibitorDetailViewController : UIViewController
{

}
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *theTitle;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLabel;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
    @property (strong ,nonatomic) NSArray *exhibitorDetailModal;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LabelExhibitorDescription;

@end
```

Why isn't the UILabel text being populated?

Thanks.

Edit:

I have logged the 'outgoing' description of the array - [arrayOfExhibitors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] and this shows the correct data as expected which is the same as the _exhibitorDetailModal.description which is shown in the detail view.

Comment: If you're on iOS 7, try scrolling the table view up and down, and see if the label gets populated. I've seen this behavior, but I don't know the root cause.

Comment: Yeah I'm using Xcode5 - iOS7.  The tableView seems fine, I can scroll it up/down and clicking on the cells loads the detail view - I can then hit the back button in the nag controller and go back to the tableView which is ok again allowing me to click on other cells etc.

Comment: did you try to log the `[arrayOfExhibitors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method ?

Comment: Yes I have checked this, the NSLog for [arrayOfExhibitors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] gives a description of the exhibitor as expected.  I have even logged the 'receiving property' on the viewDidLoad of the detail view NSLog(@"0 - %@", _exhibitorDetailModal.description); and this shows exactly the same.

Comment: It looks like you are populating the title with data from the master table view.  That is not MVC.  You should be taking data from the Model (database in this case).

Comment: Is setting the title property of the detail view controller not the correct way of doing it? exhibitorDetailViewControllerInstance.theTitle = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;  This doesn't explain why the title property can be changed this way but a label on the view cannot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this working in the end I rewrote the entire code and tidied it up along the way.

To get the UILabel displaying properly I first passed the description property of the exhibitorDetailModal object to an NSString.

```
_stringExhibitorDescription = _exhibitorDetailModal.description;
```

I then initialised the UILabel.

```
self.labelExhibitorName = [[UILabel alloc]init];
```

Then set the text of the UILabel to be that of the NSString above

```
 [_labelExhibitorName setText:_stringExhibitorName];
```

Then added the UILabel as a subView of UIView.

```
[self.view addSubview:_labelExhibitorDescription];
```